# '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, npm

*When I use npm run build in windows10 I hit this error
My package.json like this*

```
    {
  "name": "ng-matero",
  "version": "10.3.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ng-matero/ng-matero/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://ng-matero.github.io/ng-matero/",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "../node_modules/.bin/tsc -p tsconfig.json"
  },
  "schematics": "./collection.json",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

Comment: This package.json is a child, and expect use parent directory's node_modules/.bin

Answer (score 0):

`npm run` will automatically check parent `node_modules` directories, so you can remove the `..` in the `package.json` file.

```
        "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json"
```

The above will find the `tsc` installed in `../node_modules` unless there is a `tsc` installed in `node_modules`.